# How to randomize images in WordPress with Javascript (Advanced custom fields)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to build a WordPress site. One of the pages needs to have a header image that changes randomly after a couple of seconds. I am trying to make it possible to choose which images will be randomly displayed with ACF.

With ACF I have created a custom field called Random images.[image: ACF]

In the next step, the images will be loaded by the PHP template. Afterward, the images should be randomized with Javascript and shown on the page where I use the custom field. How do I do to make this work?

**PHP & Javascript**

```
<?php
if (get_row_layout() == 'random_images') {
?>
    <section id="gallery">
    <img src="' <?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_one'); ?>
    <img src="' <?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_two'); ?>
    <img src="' <?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_three'); ?> 
    <img src="' <?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_four'); ?>
    <img src="' <?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_five'); ?>
    </section>
    <?php
}
?>

<script>
const getRandomNumber = (function() {
  var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  var current = [];
  function rand(n) {
      return (Math.random() * n)|0;
  }
  return function() {
    if (!current.length) current = nums.slice();
    return current.splice(rand(current.length), 1);
  }
}());

const images = document.querySelectorAll('#gallery img');

getRandomImages = () => {
const imagesNums = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  imagesNums.push(getRandomNumber());
}

images.forEach((img, index) => {
    img.src = `./images/${imagesNums[index]}.jpg`
})
}

setInterval(() => {
 getRandomImages()
}, 500);

</script
```

Comment: Do you only want to show one image at random? Or do you want to show all 5 images but in a random order? e.g. three, two, five, one, four in one random case

Comment: I want to show one of the images at the time.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to create 1 empty section.

```
<section id="gallery"></section>
```

Now add all images to the javascript array.

```
<script>
var images = [
    '<?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_one'); ?>',
    '<?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_two'); ?>',
    '<?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_three'); ?>',
    '<?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_four'); ?>',
    '<?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_five'); ?>'
];
</script>
```

Now add the random image logic.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#gallery').html('<img class="fade-in" src="' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">');
}, 3000);
```

and some CSS to smooth transition.

```
.fade-in{
  -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s ease;
  -moz-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  -ms-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  -o-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  animation: fade-in 2s ease;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
@-o-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
@keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
```

Check the working snippet below.

**UPDATE**
(as per OP's request now the image will change automatically)

```js
var images = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=123',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=456',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=789',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=ABC',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=PQR',
];

$('#gallery').html('<img class="fade-in" src="' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">');

setInterval(function(){
    $('#gallery').html('<img class="fade-in" src="' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">');
}, 3000);
```

```css
.fade-in{
  -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s ease;
  -moz-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  -ms-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  -o-animation: fade-in ease-in-out 2s both;
  animation: fade-in 2s ease;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
@-o-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
@keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0} 100%{opacity:1}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="gallery"></section>
```

Comment: This seems to be a great solution, but I can't get it to work. The images aren't visible on WordPress. I must have implemented it wrongly somehow. This is how it looks. What do you suggest?: codepen.io/Atise/pen/YzQMMdX

Comment: I have imported jQuery to functions.php this way: >> CODE >> wp_register_script( 'jQuery', 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', null, null, true ); wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification that you want to show one image at a time, you could do the randomization in PHP, I think it will be easier:

```
<?php
if (get_row_layout() == 'random_images') {
    $field_names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
    shuffle($field_names); // this randomizes that array
    $name = $field_names[0];
?>
    <section id="gallery">
    <img src="' <?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_' . $name); ?>" />
    </section>
    <?php
}
?>
```

That will choose a random image at load time and display it.

By the way, your snippet code forgot to include the `" />` closing part of each `img` element, so I've added that here.

It still wasn't clear to me if you wanted to loop through the images with javascript randomly, so if you want that, you could do this:

```
<?php
if (get_row_layout() == 'random_images') {
    $field_names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
    shuffle($field_names); // this randomizes that array
?>
    <section id="gallery">
    <?php foreach ($field_names as $field) { ?>
        <img style="display: none;" src="' <?php get_sub_field('ra_photo_' . $field); ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    </section>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Then you could go on to loop through on a timer in javascript showing one image at a time. You'll need the proper CSS and Javascript functions to do that.